# Lob Coulmn to use in JPA Specification on Criteria builder

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, specifications, lob

```
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;
```

Above property in an Entity, which is a blob data type in the Postgres database, it stores as `bigint`(byte location, I guess in db) in table.

I have written JPA specification for the entity with all the property which works properly.

```
if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(criteria.getMessage())) {
            predicateList.add(cb.like(root.get("message"), "%" + criteria.getMessage() + "%"));
            isFilterEmpty = false;
   }
```

above code is a specification impl on the message property in the table, since `bigint` is stored in the table, specification query does not convert `bigint` to text(`lo_get` posgres method to convert to original text value), it uses `bigint` value itself to compare on `like`, so it throws an error.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: text ~~ bigint
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

How to address this issue?  Temporarily I have not added this filter in the specification, after data fetch, I have impl to filter based on message